# How to extract on the public page user posts on restfb?

Tags: java, restfb

I want to extract just user Posts using RestFB but it seems there is no way to do it.

/{page-id}/feed - gives all posts Page owner + users

/{page-id}/posts - gives all the owner posts

But i want just user posts, any way ?

```
Connection<Post> postsPages = facebookClient.fetchConnection(page + "/feed",Post.class,
                    Parameter.with("fields", "id,name,message,story,link,description,created_time,likes.limit(10).summary(true),"
                            + "comments.limit(10).summary(true),shares"), 
                    // add comments (comments.limit(10000).summary(true){id,message}
                    Parameter.with("until", "now"),
                     Parameter.with("since", START_DATE),
                    Parameter.with("limit", 100));
            List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
```